# Visual Studio 11 ARM project generator fails

Tags: windows-8, cmake, arm, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

CMake version 2.8.9

I am writing an app for Windows 8 to run on tablets.  I have written an underlying C++ library that contains the majority of my application logic.  I am using CMake to compile this C++ library because I want to have a platform-independent build system for future ports.

When I run cmake.exe from the command line or use cmake-gui, I can generate projects using the "Visual Studio 11" and "Visual Studio 11 Win64" generators.  However, when I try to use the "Visual Studio 11 ARM" generator I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
  The C compiler "cl" is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

The cause is in the more detailed output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cmTryCompileExec2764216458, Configuration: Debug ARM ------

1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Platforms\ARM\PlatformToolsets\v110\Microsoft.Cpp.ARM.v110.targets(36,5):
error MSB8022: Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It appears that by default the "Visual Studio 11 ARM" generator doesn't work because cl.exe will not allow CMake to test the compiler.

I've read that I can turn off compiler checks altogether but that sounds like a poor choice.  Is this just a bug in CMake?

Comment: If you open the targets file where the error occurs, you will see that this error is emitted if none of the following build properties is true:  `$(DesignTimeBuild)`, `$(WindowsSDKDesktopARMSupport)`, and `$(WindowsAppContainer)`.  You need to get CMake to define one of those properties.  If this test is just to verify that the compiler can build something, just define `$(WindowsSDKDesktopARMSupport)` to be true.  I have no idea how to get CMake to define this property, but it must be possible.  (I assume CMake isn't going to try to run the executable, since doing so is impossible.)

Comment: I found a bug report while looking around on cmake.org that has not yet been resolved: http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=13511

Comment: A similar bug appears to have been resolved: http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=13077

Comment: James, Is it possible to set $(DesignTimeBuild), $(WindowsSDKDesktopARMSupport), or $(WindowsAppContainer) via a /D argument to the cl commandline?

Comment: No, those are MSBuild properties (i.e., properties used during the complete build, not used by the compiler).  CMake generates MSBuild project files, so it can set these properties.  I don't use CMake, so I can't help you with how to do so (and I definitely don't know how to do so during the configuration that it's doing here).  Best of luck, though :-)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I should have posted the workaround I used.

Instead of using the 'Visual Studio 11 ARM' generator, I switched to NMake and was able to get it working.  The guys over at CMake will probably fix the Visual Studio generator in their 2.8.11 release.

The trick to using NMake to build for ARM is just to run the batch script that sets up your environment to cross-compile before invoking cmake.  Or, you could also just open "VS2012 ARM Cross Tools Command Prompt".  The batch script is located at:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_arm\vcvarsx86_arm.bat

The command line I used for cmake was:

> cmake -D "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" -G "NMake Makefiles" "path-to-CMakeLists.txt"

You can substitute "Release" for "Debug" of course.  I think everyone should do out of source builds, but you can run the command in the same directory as your CMakeLists.txt and omit the last parameter.

In order to build successfully, you will need to set the following in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /D_ARM_WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP_SDK_AVAILABLE" )
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /D_ARM_WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP_SDK_AVAILABLE" )
```

If you are building for multiple platforms, a good way that I found to detect that I was building for ARM to set the above variables was to check the environment:

```
STRING( TOLOWER "$ENV{Platform}" generator )
IF( generator STREQUAL "arm" )
```

I don't think this last part is necessary, but I noticed that there are a lot of standard libraries missing in the ARM SDK, so I setup the libraries to exclude everything that is unavailable by setting the following:

```
SET( CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "kernel32.lib user32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib advapi32.lib" 
     CACHE STRING "Libraries linked by default with all C applications." FORCE )
SET( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "kernel32.lib user32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib advapi32.lib"
     CACHE STRING "Libraries linked by default with all C++ applications." FORCE )
```

When you're all finished, just run:

```
nmake
```

Anyway, this worked for me.  I don't think I had to do anything else to get it working for my particular project.  Good luck!

Comment: I am in the same situation with my project and will try to go over the steps here to see if it works for me also. Hopes it does. One comment. The idea is to use Cmake to generate the Nmake files? (i dont know nmake). When you run nmake, does this then generate VS solutions ?

Comment: I still see "It fails with the following output: Change Dir: C:/Development/test/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp" on the cl simple test. when i do it from command line

Comment: NMake does not give you VS solutions.  It simply builds your code from the command line.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha(v=vs.71).aspx.  I generate a VS solution in x64 to develop and test my code, then I use NMake to run my final builds whether it be for x64, x86, or ARM.

Answer (score 3):

After some investigation, this is just a bug in CMake.

http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=13511

Fixing it appears to have been pushed to the CMake 2.8.11 release.  :(

Still looking for a workaround.

Comment: Hi, you manage to find a workaround? <AppContainerApplication>true</AppContainerApplication> to <PropertyGroup> section of test project (CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln) - I can't locate any CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln file. thx.

Comment: CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln is a generated file.  The above mentioned link from Eld discusses that issue.